Replacing words in a MS Word file with docxedit library
I'm using docxedit library to copy a MS Word file and replace some words in a newly created file.
I use this code below,
docxedit.replace_string(doc, old_string='JSY', new_string='1')

but when I run the Python file, the terminal is like this...
Error: Could not find JSY
Error: Could not find JSY
Error: Could not find JSY
Error: Could not find JSY
Error: Could not find JSY
Success: Replaced JSY with WKJ
Error: Could not find JSY
Error: Could not find JSY

and I can see that in the new file "JSY" is replaced with "1".
What's wrong with this.. how can I fix it?
I have no idea why the error messages are shown in the terminal a lot
with success message included...

can you provide more of your code pls?

thank you Mr. Irrelevant! I found the reason :)
